# C++ --> error: expected ')' before 'conf'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I don't understand where is error... 
It gives me: error: expected ')' before 'conf' when I build...

This is generic.cpp file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "generic.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


Generic(dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf ) //Costruttore
{
   this->conf = conf;
}

int Generic::addInt(std::string name, int value)
{
   dynamic_reconfigure::IntParameter int_param;
   std::cout << "Insert an integer value of " << name << ":\n";
   std::cin >> value;
   std::cout << "Setting " << name << "\n\n";
   std::cout << "Matched value: " << value << "\n\n";
   int_param.name=name;
   int_param.value=value;
   this->conf.ints.push_back(int_param);

return value;
}
```

Here there is generic.h file:

```
 #ifndef GENERIC_H_INCLUDED
 #define GENERIC_H_INCLUDED
 #include <string>
 #include <dynamic_reconfigure/IntParameter.h>
 #include <dynamic_reconfigure/Config.h>

 class Generic{

    dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf;

    public:
    Generic(dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf ); //Costruttore

    int addInt(std::string name, int value);
};

 #endif // GENERIC_H_INCLUDED
```

I also tried to put dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf as public but nothing.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor is a member of the class, and when you define a member outside of the class definition you need to specify the class name and then the member name, like

```
Generic::Generic(dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf ) //Costruttore
^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
 class    member
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! Really useful! I Thank to other people too!

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor definition is `Generic` in your code, you need `Generic::Generic`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your constructor properly, with class specification:

```
Generic::Generic(dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf)
^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, help us help you by pasting the compiler's output - or at least the line regarding the specific error you encounter (including the line of code causing this error).

Secondly, it's not advised to `#include <string>` or any other include for that matter in the header file. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/1778249 for when its useful.